# Reading all rows from database and putting them into ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I've the below code,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
    for(int i=1; i<=columnsNumber; i++){
        inner.add(rs.getString(i));
    }                   
}
outer.add(inner);
return outer;
```

What I get for outer is something like this

```
[[100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300]]
```

What I'm trying to get is

```
[[100, 200, 300], [100, 200, 300]]
```

I want each row to be an unique item in the list, but what I get is a list of all rows in one item in the list.

How do I do it?

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new inner for each record and add it to outer.

```
ArrayList<String> inner; 
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

while (rs.next()) {
    inner = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(int i=1; i<=columnsNumber; i++){
       inner.add(rs.getString(i));
    }    
    outer.add(inner);               
}
```

Comment: You are a genious. It helped me buddy

Answer (score 2):

On each step of the `while` loop, you have to re-initialize the `inner` list with an empty one and and add it to the `outer` list before the step has finished:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    inner = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=columnsNumber; i++){
        inner.add(rs.getString(i));
    }                   
    outer.add(inner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `outer` is a list of lists, in each iteration of the `while` loop you will need to:

1. Reinitialize the `inner` list
2. Fill the `inner` list
3. Store this version of the `inner` list in the `outer` list.

I would also keep the `inner` declaration inside the `while` loop to limit its scope, like this:

```
List<List<String>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
    List<String> inner = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
       inner.add(rs.getString(i));
    }    
    outer.add(inner);               
}
return outer;
```